# DKIM check invalid with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, dkim

I've just install PHPMailer and DKIM and everything seems to be ok. DNS are replicated with DKIM record, RSA key are generated and placed at the right place. But.. result when I send a message is : invalid.

---

```
Message contains this DKIM Signature:
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; l=1713; s=dkim;
    t=1465233482; c=relaxed/simple;
    h=From:To:Date:Subject;
    d=xxxxx.xxx; i=root@localhost;
    z=From:=20=3D?UTF-8?Q?La_Mod=3DC3=3DA9ration_de_CA?=3D=20
    |To:=20cN9Ush6VQgBfiS@dkimvalidator.com
    |Date:=20Mon,=206=20Jun=202016=2019:18:02=20+0200
    |Subject:=20Suppression=20de=20votre=20compte;
    bh=IzoJggwtPQOV/aIyy0WsyBQ2qKwcfHgljU7aOHPA+JI=;
    b=

Signature Information:
v= Version:         1
a= Algorithm:       rsa-sha256
c= Method:          relaxed/simple
d= Domain:          xxxxx.xxx
s= Selector:        dkim
q= Protocol:        dns/txt
bh=                 IzoJggwtPQOV/aIyy0WsyBQ2qKwcfHgljU7aOHPA+JI=
h= Signed Headers:  From:To:Date:Subject
b= Data:            
Public Key DNS Lookup


Building DNS Query for dkim._domainkey.xxxxx.xxx
Retrieved this publickey from DNS: v=DKIM1; k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCh4qoAjuc4qrO01aWQ2wjRnbyuI3wKliRsjbPvGE4neh2ac8WiOyZeuPPoq6LuqNLQbzgkpB49b7Za88D5AOACx7RxY0ahjDF+H76us1BI62yZnAiwhS27aLNlI7DqbbcNURjRNIod/zRs/i1Empgpqf2WFLqneNS/lcADiEA7GQIDAQAB
Validating Signature


result = invalid
Details: bad identity
```

---

Something wrong.. but what ? Is it normal that "b= Data:" is empty ? When I have a look inside de PHPMailer Class, it's pretty normal, code is 'b=;' and nothing else.

Could someone be able to give me more explanations ?

Thanks a lot

FZ

Comment: How long is the key under "dkim._domainkey.xxxxx.xxx"? It looks like it got cut off.

Comment: No, it was not. The DNS record was ok. I have checked it a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Something is up with your config = the `b` param should not be empty. If you look at the code you'll see that the base64-encoded signature appended to that string via the response from the `DKMIN_sign` function, which must mean that something is going wrong inside that function, specifically, the call to `openssl_sign` must be failing, most likely that it's failing to get your private key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helps me because kwnoing the 'b' parameter must not be empty what the trigger. I've found the solutions to my problem.
First, I didn't implement SSL with PHP.. So, SSL functions wasn't working, obvioulsy
Second, the file (the private key) to be read by the function must be in 'PEM' format. So, if your remove the first and last line, it wouldn't work at all.
And last, even with SPF ok and DKIM ok, GMAIL still sees me as a phishing scammer.. Thank you Google.